# SQL Update syntax check

Tags: sql, teradata

Writing a simple update statement in Teradata and I'm having trouble getting it to work. I'm getting a syntax error saying: `Syntax error: expected something between the word 'First_name' and the 'FROM' keyword` . This is reference to line 7. I have no idea what I'm missing.

Here's the code with some redacted object names:

`UPDATE DATA.CONTACTS tgt
SET 
     tgt.LAST_NAME = TABLES.PART.LAST_NAME
    ,tgt.BPP_USER_ID = TABLES.PART.User_Id
    ,tgt.Email_Address = TABLES.PART.Email
    ,tgt.Last_name = TABLES.PART.Last_name
    ,tgt.First_name = TABLES.PART.First_name
FROM
  (SELECT 
   C_C
  , USER_ID
  , Email
  ,Last_name
  ,First_name
  FROM TABLES.PART) --ppage
WHERE  EMAIL_ADDRESS IN (
  SELECT Email 
  FROM DATA.CONTACTS
  );`

select * from mmbi_tables_data.crm_mmbi_contacts

I've tried deleting using that ppage alias but I still get the same error regardless of what I do.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look so simple.  I think the following will work in Teradata:

```
UPDATE tgt
    FROM data.contacts tgt, tables.part ppage
    SET LAST_NAME = TABLES.PART.LAST_NAME,
        BPP_USER_ID = TABLES.PART.User_Id,
        Email_Address = TABLES.PART.Email,
        Last_name = TABLES.PART.Last_name,
        First_name = TABLES.PART.First_name
    WHERE tgt.email = ppage.email_address;
```